# Detecting when an image has been resized in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, lightbox

My blog posts live in a container that's 600px wide. When I have an image that's wider than 600px, I resize it via CSS (`.post img {max-width: 600px}`)

I'd like users to be able to click on these resized images and see the full size version in a lightbox, but to do this I need to detect in Javascript which images have been thus resized (since I don't want to lightbox images that appear full size inline in the post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the image element's `width` property to get the rendered width of the image. If it's `600`, the image is most likely to be shrinked. However, the image might originally as well be exactly 600 pixels wide.

If a browser supports the new HTML 5 [`naturalWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLImageElement#DOM.c2.a0properties) property, you can get the original image width (in pixels) and compare that with the value of `clientWidth`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can in the sense you are speaking as JS is going to read the image it is in the DOM. However what if you set the `max-width` in the JS:

Just Psuedocode

```
onload
{
    if (img.width > 600px)
    {
        img.style = max-width: 600px;
        img.lightbox();
    }
}
```

Comment: A minor drawback will be the 'jump' effect after the images have been loaded, due to the rerendering of the page. Not to mention the horror you'll see when JS is switched off/unavailable for one reason or another (but that happens not that often).

Comment: CSS could be overridden with JS in order to allow for "graceful degradation". Also the page jump could be smoothed out with JS. In the end how bad do @Horace want the desired effect. I personally would go with utilizing the lightbox on all images for a more consistent user experience.